# Could not unlock file inside Application contents

Tags: macos, ios, filesystem, file, android

For using RoboVM on OSX, I need to edit a file called info.plist, which resides inside the contents of the application called Android Studio.

Last year I managed to edit the file for Android Studio 1.5 (right image), but I now installed Android Studio 2.13 and I didn't succeed (left image).

It seems that the contents of this application are read only. How do I edit this file? I only need to change one value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're an admin you can add write permission to the group using the chmod command:

```
sudo chmod g+w /path/to/info.plist
```

**Update:**  Turns out they were launching the application directly from the disk image, which was likely mounted as read-only. Copying it to the local disk lets you make changes like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the path to the .dmg file, but I do not know the path to the info.plist file which resides inside the contents of the package. The properties say that I have read and write access, but it says above it "Read only". I cannot say for example: /path/to/dmg/Contents/Info.plist

Comment: Oh- this file lives inside a disk image? I assume the disk image is read-only then. Where will the file end up? Are you running this from the disk image or installing (copying) to a local disk?

Comment: Yes, it does. I am not sure. When I open it, it shows two icons. Android Studio with a logo and a shortcut to the Applications folder. I just double click on Android Studio and it will launch the application. But as you can see in the screenshot: Previously I could just open the application directly from my desktop. The location is different now.

Comment: Ah, you're just launching from the read-only disk image it sounds like. Try copying it it your Applications folder. Then control-click (right-click) on the copy in /Applications and select "Show Package Contents" and look for the file somewhere in there.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like I just needed to copy it to my hard drive. I'm new to OSX :) Maybe you can update the answer?

Comment: No problem! Yeah, disk images can be a strange concept. Technically, you might have been able to make the disk image read-write and do it in there but you probably just want to copy the application to the local disk and then make your changes there. Welcome to the fold!